# Using MySql PASSWORD() function from hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, password-encryption

I'm rewriting old java desktop swing app to JSF application using PrimeFaces.

The old app didn't use hibernate but I have decided to use it in new app. Everything works fine but the problem is when I want to save passwords with hibernate using MySql’s function password().

Is there a way to do this because it would be nice if I could import data from old database to new database without changing passwords.

I managed to bring login to work using this code snippet:

```
public User login(String username, String password) {

    User result = null;

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        String sql = "select s from User where username=:username and password=password(:password)";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
        query.setString("username", username);
        query.setString("password", password);

        result = (User) query.uniqueResult();

        if (result != null) {
            Hibernate.initialize(result.getUserData());
        }
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

But here is problem with registration of new users since I don't know how store passwords. The code I’m using to save users to database looks like:

```
public User addUser(User obj) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        session.save(obj);
        session.flush();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I know I could write the whole insert statement the old fashioned way but what’s the point of using hibernate then and the code would look ugly. Also I’m not happy with login snippet as well. 
I’ve also tried to update password with trigger after insert but I kept getting error:

```
Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger
```

So I abandoned this approach since its ugly and it doesn’t work.

Should I just use [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org) or any other library to encrypt password in applications and be done with it? Or is there an elegant solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jasypt [EncryptedStringType](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html#Using_annotations) is much more convenient, since you delegate the password hashing to the UserType.

This way your application logic doesn't have to deal with password related responsibilities (like it's the case of your SELECT using the non-portable PASSWORD SQL function).

The UserType will also take care of hashing the actual password for an INSERT/UPDATE too.

So, [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html) is a much better alternative.

Comment: Maybe i overlooked something, but is the Jasypt library not meant for encryption? I couldn't find any hash functions and user passwords should certainly be hashed not encrypted.

Comment: Encryption can be one-way (hashing) or two-ways(private and public keys). Hashing can be done with MD5, SHA-1 or SHA-2 and Jasypt supports those.

Comment: Ok, finally i found the page i searched for and it seems that one way hashes are indeed [supported](http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html), there is also some [example code](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html). Usually one distinguishes between encryption (two-way) and hashing (one-way).

Comment: In college, I learned this stuff during the Communication theory, encoding and encryption' course. The hashing theory is a branch of encryption.

Answer (score 3):

The MySql function [password()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) should not be used at all for hashing passwords! From the documentation:

> The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL
>   Server; you should not use it in your own applications.

The calculation is fast and unsalted, which makes it **very** unsecure. Instead leave the hashing to the server side language and use a library which uses a slow hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt. A wellknown library for Java is [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).